# What is in reality "endl" (or any output manipulator)? How is it implemented and how does it work with operator<<?

Tags: c++, output, iomanip

What is actually `endl`? Of course, it prints a new line and flushes the ostream buffer. But what is it actually?  Can such "entities" like `endl` be defined by the programer?

There are these "output manipulators" which can be accessed using the library `iomanip` but what is actually going on when executing a command such as: `cout << setprecision(5);`

`setprecision()` looks like a function call, yet nothing is printed when using the `cout` instance. It changes the precision, but why simply not use the corresponding function member instead of adding more "abstraction" to code writing? By abstraction i mean non-intuitive code.

Thanks!

Comment: `endl` is a "new line"+`flush()`, they are functors (or a sort of)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Comment: That *"abstraction"* allows chaining: `std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;` instead of `std::cout << "hello"; std::endl(std::cout);`

Comment: @Jarod42 So the return type is ostream& ? What i would really like to know if is it possible to define functions with no parameters which can be called without using the syntax ``function()`` (without the parentheses)

Comment: These methods _do_ have parameters though, they just happen to match the parameters that are later passed in through `ostream::operator<<`. Thus you're passing a reference to them, essentially. (These kind are identity functions, implemented as functors. They take in an ostream, mutate it, and return it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is actually endl? Of course, it prints a new line and flushes the ostream buffer. But what is it actually?

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function. It

> Inserts a newline character into the output sequence os and flushes it

---

> Can such "entities" like endl be defined by the programer?

Yes.

Here's a demo program.

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& test_manip(std::ostream& out)
{
   return (out << "In test_manip\n");
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << test_manip;
}
```

and its output.

```
In test_manip
```

Comment: What's happened to "In "?

Comment: Thank you! But does this work only when using ``cout`` ?

Comment: @Some1, it works for all `std::ostream` objects. Should workf for `std::ofstream` as well as `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is actually `endl`? Of course, it prints a new line and flushes the ostream buffer. But what is it actually?

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function, that takes an `std::ostream&` reference as input and returns a `std::ostream&` reference as output:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

[`std::basic_ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) has an overload that accepts a pointer to such a function:

```
template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
> class basic_ostream : virtual public std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>
{
    ...
    basic_ostream& operator<<(
        std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&)
    );
    ...
};
```

This overload will call the passed function, giving it the `std::ostream` object that the operator is being called on, eg:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) )
{
    func(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

The implementation of `std::endl` can then write to the given `std::ostream` and flush it, eg:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os )
{
    os.put(os.widen('\n'));
    os.flush();
    return os;
}
```

So, when you have a statement like this:

```
std::cout << std::endl
```

It would actually call this internally:

```
std::cout.operator<<(&std::endl)
```

Which would then call:

```
std::endl(std::cout)
```

> Can such "entities" like endl be defined by the programer?

Yes.  Any function that matches the above signature (`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&)`) can be passed to `operator<<`.

> what is actually going on when executing a command such as: `cout << setprecision(5);`
>
> `setprecision()` looks like a function call

It *IS* a function call.  I/O manipulators that take user input work a little differently then I/O manipulators that do not take any user input.

In order to apply the user input to a `std::ostream` object (or a `std::istream` object), such a manipulator *returns* an instance of an implementation-defined type that holds the input, and then overloads the non-member `operator<<` to take that type.  When that overload is called, it can then apply the input to the `std::ostream` (or `std::istream`) as needed.

In the case of `std::setprecision()`, it takes an `int` as input, and returns an implementation-defined type that holds that `int`, and then that type passes the `int` to `std::ostream::precision()`, eg:

```
struct PrecisionType { int value; };

PrecisionType setprecision( int n )
{
    return PrecisionType{ n };
}

template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, const PrecisionType &input )
{
    os.precision(input.value);
    return os;
}
```

Thus, a statement like this:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5)
```

Would actually call something like this:

```
PrecisionType temp = std::setprecision(5);
operator<<(std::cout, temp)
```

Which will then internally call:

```
std::cout.precision(temp.value)
```

> yet nothing is printed when using the cout instance.  It changes the precision

Correct, because the manipulator that `set::setprecision()` returns does not write anything to the output buffer of the `std::ostream`, it merely tweaks the `std::ostream` itself.

There is nothing stopping an I/O manipulator from writing to a `std::ostream` (or reading from a `std::istream`) if it wants to, though.

> why simply not use the corresponding function member instead of adding more "abstraction" to code writing?

You certainly could call the members directly, but then you would not be able to chain subsequent expressions using `<<`.  Having each manipulator return a reference to the `std::ostream` (or `std::istream`) object being manipulated is what allows the chaining.  The member methods do not return such references.

For example:

```
cout << setprecision(5) << 123.45 << endl;
```

Translates to this:

```
operator<<(cout, setprecision(5)).operator<<(123.45).operator<<(&endl);
```

Which would ultimately call something like this internally:

```
//operator<<(cout, setprecision(5));
cout.precision(5);

//cout.operator<<(123.45);
use_facet<num_put<char>>(cout.getloc()).put(
  ostreambuf_iterator it{cout},
  cout,
  cout.fill(),
  123.45
);

//cout.operator<<(&endl)
endl(cout);
```

Not as pretty as just using `<<` overloads, is it?